# I cant find a way to dynamically enter value in the object field which includes a array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

this is the object . How can i input value through form tag in listItem key dynamically in react

```
 { 
   name: "", 
   dueDate: "", 
   grossAmount: "", 
   billNo: "", 
   billDate: "" ,
   listItem:[{ productName: "", quantity: null, price: null, amount: null, gstRate: null}], 
   gstAmount: null, 
   netAmount: null, 
   notes: "", 
   status: " "
}
```

Comment: Is this object stored inside a state by using `useState`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming object is stored in a state using useState hook

```
const [obj,setObj] = useState({ 
       name: "", 
       dueDate: "", 
       grossAmount: "", 
       billNo: "", 
       billDate: "" ,
       listItem:[{ productName: "", quantity: null, price: null, amount: null, gstRate: null}], 
       gstAmount: null, 
       netAmount: null, 
       notes: "", 
       status: " "
    })
```

You can do..

state for input:

```
const [productName,setProductName] = useState("");
```

And for input you can do something like this. Note: I just did this for changing productName, but you can do this for any of the other keys of the obj.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setProductName(e.target.value)} />
  <button onClick={()=>setObj({...obj,lastItem:[...lastItem[0],productName]})}></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add `name` attribute to your input element. Then create a onChangeHandler function. This function can handle all changes for every inputs you have.
Your inputs (the name attribute should be the same as your object key):

```
<input name='dueDate' onChange={onChangeHandler} type="text" value={myObject.dueDate} />
```

onChangeHandler function:

```
const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    myObject = {
        return {...myObject, [event.targer.name]: event.targer.value}
    }
}
```